# fetch cngroup with identifier using Contacts framework

Tags: ios, cncontactstore

I created a group using CNMutableGroup, by the time of creation , the identifier of the group is :

```
 A9A00074-CA8F-4EA4-8E76-F26C37CB49B4:ABGroup
```

I saved this in NSUserDefaults.

The documentation says:

> It is recommended that you use the identifier when re-fetching the
>   group. The identifier can be persisted between app launches.

How can I use this identifier to fetch the group ?

If I do:

```
    CNMutableGroup *group = [CNMutableGroup new];
    group.name=kGroup;
```

this creates a new identifier even though the group name is same.

I couldn't set the identifier as it is read only.

I tried:

```
 NSPredicate *predicate = [CNGroup predicateForGroupsInContainerWithIdentifier:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"groupIDentifier"]];
 NSArray *groups = [store groupsMatchingPredicate:predicate error:&saveError];
```

The groups is nil.

How can I access the group with the identifier ?

Comment: A9A00074-CA8F-4EA4-8E76-F26C37CB49B4:ABGroup @matt

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why, but `predicateForGroupsWithIdentifiers` worked for me:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [CNGroup predicateForGroupsWithIdentifiers:@[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"groupIDentifier"]]];
NSArray *groups = [store groupsMatchingPredicate:predicate error:&saveError];
```